# Awk to average column based on key in 2nd column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have

```
Sample_A   100
Sample_A   200
Sample_B   300
Sample_B   100
```

And I want to print the average of the values in row 2 for each key in row 1

```
Sample_A   150
Sample_B   200
```

I can print the sums of the values in row 2 for each key in row 1 using the excellent answer to another question:
[Sum First Column on basis of Second Column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419995/sum-first-column-on-basis-of-second-column)

The command is:

```
awk 'NR { k = $1; cnt[k] += $2 } END { print; for (k in cnt) print k,cnt[k]}' File.txt
```

And this produces

```
Sample_A  300
Sample_B  400
```

But in order to calculate the average, I need a way to save the number of occurrences of the key, something like

```
awk 'NR { k = $1; cnt[k] += $2; count(k)=$2} END { print; for (k in cnt) print k,cnt[k]/count(k)}' File.txt
```

But my `count(k)` code is kind of a shot in the dark and doesn't work.

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines, except awk arrays are accessed using square brackets rather than parentheses and you need to *increment* `count` rather than assign `$2` to it i.e. `count[k]++` or `count[k] += 1`

Answer (score 4):

With `awk` you could do:

```
awk '{seen[$1]+=$2; count[$1]++} END{for (x in seen)print x, seen[x]/count[x]}' infile
Sample_A 150
Sample_B 200
```

Or using GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
datamash -t' ' --sort --group 1 mean 2 <infile
Sample_A 150
Sample_B 200
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ sum[$1] += $2; count[$1] += 1 } END { for ( key in count ) { print key, sum[key] / count[key] } }' input
Sample_A 150
Sample_B 200
```

To derive a mean, you need two things: a count of the number of entities being averaged, and the sum of those values.  We use an array, `count` for the former, and an array `sum` for the latter.  The keys in each array are the assigned to the first column in your data file.

We then use an `END` clause once the data are being collected to look at each array to get the sums and counts, divide one by the other, and display the results.

The `awk` script, reformatted to not all be on one line, looks like this:

```
{ 
  sum[$1] += $2 
  count[$1] += 1
} 
END { 
  for (key in count) { 
    print key, sum[key] / count[key] 
  } 
}
```

Comment: your answer is duplicated of what I posted!

Comment: Form follows function, my friend.