# To get average of columns for all the entries whose first column entries are duplicate

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
30901 foo1 bar1 89
30902 foo2 bar2 51
30903 foo3 bar3 101
30903 foox bary 12
30903 fooz bara 23
30903 foob barc 62
30904 fooe barf 59
...
...
```

I want my output to have output like this:

```
30901 89
30902 51
30903 49.5
...
```

`49.5` being the average of fourth column, for all four duplicate entries for id: `30903` in column 1.

All I could do was to get number of unique entries using
`cat <logfile> | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c`
to get the count of duplicate entries based on first column (id)

Comment: Closely related: [Awk to average column based on key in 2nd column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465811/awk-to-average-column-based-on-key-in-2nd-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 awk '{c[$1]++ ; t[$1]+=$4 }  
    END { for (cc in c ) if ( c[cc]>1 ) printf "%s : %.1f\n",cc,t[cc]/c[cc];}' file.log
```

which give

```
30903 : 49.5
```

to get your output, remove `if (c[cc]>1)` part.

the script basically count `c[$1]++` and add `t[$1]+=$4` value.

- `c[x]` is for count(x), that is `$1` : first field
- `t[x]` is for total(x), that is sum of total value for 4'th field

at the end, we loop over all values, computing and printing average.

Comment: More descriptive variable names would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you it works fine. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @glennjackman Descriptive names in a throwaway twp-liner in Awk? What for. It's a bit ironic that the loop dummy `cc` has a longer name than the `c` and `t` globals, though.

Answer (score 0):

With Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) you can run

```
mlr --nidx stats1 -a mean -f 4 -g 1 inputFile
```

and have

```
30901 89.000000
30902 51.000000
30903 49.500000
30904 59.000000
```

- `-f 4` to set the Value-field names on which to compute statistics (the fourth field);
- `-g 1` to set group-by-field names (the first field).

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. I cannot confirm it because I am using Fedora OS and I couldn't find Miller for fedora.

Comment: @Mr_S here you have the generic linux binary (mlr.linux.x86_64
) https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0